# R and MySQL set up

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

So I'm trying to set up a MySQL database in R, and after reading through many tutorials and StackOverflow posts I'm still not able to setup a connection. I'm retrieving financial data for healthcare companies via the Quandl web API, and want to store some of the data in a SQL database and retrieve. Here is my code:

```
    #Install and load Quandl package
    install.packages("Quandl")
    library(Quandl)

    #Install and load SQL package
    install.packages("RMySQL")
    library(RMySQL)

    #Authenicate API key
    Quandl.api_key("________")

    #Load top 10 biggest Healthcare compaines in Fortune 500 according to 
    #http://fortune.com/2015/06/20/fortune-500-biggest-healthcare-companies/
    CVS <- Quandl("WIKI/CVS")
    McKesson <- Quandl("WIKI/MCK")
    UnitedHealthGroup <- Quandl("WIKI/UNH")
    AmerisourceBergern <- Quandl("WIKI/ABC")
    ExpressScriptsHolding <- Quandl("WIKI/ESRX")
    CardinalHealth <- Quandl("WIKI/CAH")
    Walgreens <- Quandl("WIKI/WBA")
    Johnson_Johnson <- Quandl("WIKI/JNJ")
    Anthem <- Quandl("WIKI/ANTM")
    Aetna <- Quandl("WIKI/AET")

    con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                user = 'root',
                password = 'password',
                host = 'localhost',
                dbname = 'healthcare')
```

I've installed mysql-5.7.17-winx64 and it's in the same directory that I'm working in in RStudio. When I try to run the dbConnect() command, I get an error saying:

'Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (0)'

Is there something I need to do with the SQL files? What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you access your MySQL from the command line or from Workbench?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not very well versed in the Windows command line, how would I try that?

Comment: Try launching MySQL.  This is the first thing you should try before posting here.  It's probably under your start menu.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't see anything in my start menu, but I navigated to C:\Users\weise\OneDrive\Documents\mysql-5.7.17-winx64\mysql-5.7.17-winx64\bin\mysql.exe  and it opened up a window for a second then closed.

Comment: Try using MySQL from the command line.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What would be the command for that? Like I said I am not familiar with the Windows command line.

Comment: Have a look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay so that says to run the command `mysql db_name` but the command line says that it is not a recognized command.

Comment: You need to go to the folder where MySQL is actually installed. Look under `Program Files`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay so I navigated to that same mysql.exe file in the command line and I'm getting this: 
`C:\Users\weise\Documents\mysql-5.7.17-winx64\mysql-5.7.17-winx64\bin>mysql.exe
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`

Comment: Your MySQL has a configuration problem.  You should open a new question and ask about getting that to work then.  But first, check SO to see if you can find useful articles.  SO is _not_ a forum where we go back and forth forever.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't understand how there could be a configuration problem when I just downloaded it tonight, but okay. Thanks for your help. I would've moved this to chat if I had the rep for it.

Comment: If you just set up an ODBC name and use `RODBC` your life will be *much* easier

Comment: Maybe you download was bad.  At least you know what the problem is now.

Comment: @Hack-R Do you know of a tutorial I could follow to do that?